# I want to click on second checkbox inside nested ng-repeat in Protractor Test

Tags: angularjs, protractor

My Code snippet is below..

```
<div  class="sl" ng-repeat="qual in mQuals | orderBy : 'order'">
    <div  ng-repeat="cList in tList | orderBy:'Priority' " ng-if="c == qualifier.Id">
        <p class="sl-text-body--small" title="">
            <div>
                <label class="sl-checkbox" style="cursor: pointer">
                    <input ng-model="checkList.Status"  type="checkbox" id="checkbox-01" />
                        <span class="sl-checkbox--fux"></span>  
                </label>
            </div>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Inside inner ng-repeat, It repeats two times. I am not able to click Second checkbox.

[image]

I have tried in protractor like below..

```
var checkBoxElements=element.all(by.xpath('//input[@ng-model="checkList.Status"]')).get(1);
 browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(checkBoxElements),5000);
 checkBoxElements.click().then(function () {
                        /*/!* Getting color-class of qualifier-box*!/*/

                        browser.sleep(2000);

    })
```

When I try like below..

```
var checkBoxElements=element.all(by.xpath('//input[@ng-model="checkList.Status"]')).get(0);
```

I am able to click first checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

I would advice you to generate correct ID's for the inputs.
in your case it would be something like this:

```
<input ng-model="checkList.Status"  type="checkbox" id="checkbox-{{ $parent.$index }}-{{ $index }}" />
```

where $parent.$index is the index/iterator of the outer ng-repeat and $index the index/iterator of t´he inner one.

in your protractor test you can then select the element with:

```
element.all(by.css('#checkbox-0-1')).get(0);
```